# How to get jQuery elements after declairation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created Tr with jQuery as below

```
var elemTr = $("<tr>", { 

    });

var elemEmpName = $("<div>", { }).data('otherDtls', {
    recordId: 10
});;
```

Then in elemTr appended elemEmpName

```
elemTr.append(jQuery("<td>", {}).append(elemEmpName));
```

There are n no of elemTr which will be displayed inside Table

Now if I have "elemTr" -- How should I get "elemEmpName" which is present inside it, So I can get 'otherDtls' associated with it.

Comment: Can you show rendered `HTML structure` using Firebug/Chrome console?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak It's just normal camelCase, what's your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
elemTr.find('td div').data('otherDtls')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use initial reference to do that.

// wrap it in jQuery so it becomes a collection

```
 var elemEmpName = $("<div>", { }).data('otherDtls', {
   recordId: 10
 });;
```

// append to the DOM

```
 elemTr.append(jQuery("<td>", {}).append(elemEmpName));
```

// do stuff, using the initial reference

```
  $(elemEmpName).find('otherDtls');//do something
```